# Скелет проекта с активити и фрагментами под андроид

Tags: android

Решил переписать проект с использованием фрагментов и бокового меню. Логика работы: Программа показывает экран загрузки -> если нужно открывает окно авторизации или регистрации -> открывает экран с основным функционалом. Сейчас смена экранов реализована через setContentView(). Логика проста и очевидна: setContentView(R.layout.page); плюс обработчики нажатий на кнопки этого лайоута.

С фрагментами не понятно.

1) Главный класс должен быть фрагментом или активити?

2) Можете нарисовать структуру классов? Например, я вижу логику работы такой: LoadActivity() -> LoginOrRegisterFragment() -> MainFragment(); Или главный класс сделать фрагментом и в нем менять все странички?

3) Если сейчас один основной класс, то как работать если их станет несколько? Как вызывать нативные библиотеки и передавать данные между классами?

4) Есть примеры программ с фрагментами и боковым меню? К сожалению вот этот проект собрать так и не удалось из-за проблем со стилями: http://habrahabr.ru/post/236567/

5) Сейчас я ровняюсь на Телеграмм, мне нужно сделать такое же приложение. (И желательно быстро, а не натыкаясь на очередные грабли).

Comment: фрагмент не может быть самостоятельным , он может быть только частью активити. У вас совершенная каша и полностью отсутствует понимание архитектуры андроид-приложения. Для ответа на ваш вопрос потребуется с сотню страниц печатного текста ... Возьмите учебник, рекомендую "Брайн Харди, Билл Филипс - Программирование под Android - 2014" - очень токовая книжка, когда прочитаете, спрашивайте по существу.

Comment: По тому и спрашиваю, что каша. Думаю для ответа на мой вопрос вполне хватит и 20 строчек кода.

Comment: если вы решили не натыкаться на очередные грабли , то не хватит и сотни страниц - это только основное осилить, чтобы хотя бы вопросы задавать так , чтобы получить на них полезный ответ.Нельзя просто так взять и написать андроид-приложение по 20 строчкам кода , тем более,что вы пока даже готовый пример запустить не можете.

Comment: Это не я не могу, это со средой сборки проблемы. Даже новый проект пришлось исправить, чтобы рендеринг активити заработал. Если описание основной логики приложения не вмещается в 20 строк то это не самое лучшее описание. )

Comment: Вы серьезно думаете, что вам сейчас напишут двадцать волшебных строчек и вы быстро-быстро напишите аналог telegram?

Comment: @mikelsv Проблемы не со средой сборки. Вы взяли проект для Eclipse, который настроен под эту IDE. Для использования других систем сборки необходимо делать под них (чем вам и пришлось заняться)

Comment: @pavlofff, я предполагал, что здесь находятся профессионалы, которые вполне могут поделиться кодом абсолютно типового приложения. К примеру я могу легко и просто поделиться кодом своего проекта, например: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419339/Нативная-работа-с-интерфейсом-android .  Прыжки по лайоутам и обработка кнопок. И надеялся увидеть примерно то же самое, но с использованием фрагментов. Видимо я ошибался.

Comment: Реализация кода типового приложения с нав.драйвером и фрагментами? Это на гитхабе надо постить, а не сюда. Посмотрите библиотеку [Майка Пенза](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) - типовой шаблон того, чего вы хотите тут попросить, только фрагменты свои вставить. 20 строчек говорите ... кстати,можете его библиотеку использовать

Comment: В AndroidStudio есть готовый шаблон проекта, реализующего каркас - NavigationDrawer и фрагменты, чем он вам не подходит?

Answer (score 2):

Начнем с того, что простая и очевидная для вас логика подмены ContentView очень плохая практика в андроид-разработке - она приведет вас в тупик и к напрасно потраченному на бессмысленное времени.

1. Без активити вы не сможете отобразить фрагмент, в этом плане она главная. Если вы о логике, то фрагмент - независимый от конкретной активити элемент интерфейса (должен быть таким) и соответсвенно, основная логика UI находится в нем - здесь он главный.
2. Структура типичного приложения с нав.драйвером на фрагментах такова:

   Стартовая активити, реализующая NavigationDrawer, обрабатывающая клики в нав.драйвере и подменяющяя в себе фрагменты, соответствующие пунктам нав.драйвера -> фрагмент, соответствующий выбранному пункту -> активити дополнительного экрана (по возможности следует избегать вызова фрагментов из фрагментов)
3. Если под классами имеются ввиду активити, то данные как между разными активити, так и между активити и фрагментами передаются с помощью механизма интентов перед вызовом желаемого нового экрана - данный интент прикрепляется параметром к вызову, а возвращаются с помощью методов обратного вызова. Как вызывается нативный код не ведаю, за более два года такой возможности мне не понадобилось.
4. Есть такие прграммы, гитхаб полон таких программ. Ваша проблема в том, что большинство даже совсем начинающих разработчиков может собрать простейший учебный пример без проблем. Если это у вас не получается, как вы собираетесь собирать сложное приложение. Вы надеетесь, что найдется что то такое, что соберется не только у всех остальных, но и у вас тоже? Лучше всего вам сосредоточится сейчас на проблеме, почему у всех собирается, а у вас - нет. Что ВЫ делаете не так.
5. Равнение вы себе выбрали нормальное. За сколько планируете написать такое? Неделя не больше, да? Чего там сложного, тем более без граблей - строчек пятьдесят кода :(

AndroidStudio содержит готовый стартовый шаблон с NavigationDrawer, где большая часть работы уже проделана.
Практически готовая и пожалуй лучшая  реализация приложения с NavigationDrawer - остается только добавить нужные активити и фрагменты - библиотека Майка Пенза [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)

Comment: Строчек конечно не 50, но да, недели хватило, чтобы реализовать базовый функционал: добавление контактов и посылка сообщений. Дальше меня унесло в абстракцию. https://github.com/mikelsv/zverus

Comment: @mikelsv Вы же понимаете, что сейчас вы так же далеки от готового продукта, как и неделю назад? О вашем нестандартном способе работы с UI я уже не раз говорил. Повторю:) Посмотрите хоть на работу с UI в [стандартном мессенджере](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/+/android-5.1.1_r1) android. Есть множество и [других примеров](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=messenger+android) для подражания - все они разные, но объединяет их одно - нигде вы не увидите "вашего" способа работы с UI. Мне бы очень хотелось, чтобы вы одумались и писали под платформу так, как это принято.

Comment: не думаю, что я уж сильно далек и где та грань, отличающая готовый продукт от не готового? Разрабатывать его я начал в позапрошлый четверг, и вполне рассчитываю что еще через две недели он будет завершен. Что до способов работы, ну вот не получается у меня работать по стандартам. Или я работаю по своему или никак.

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю, стоит начать с этого: [Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Comment: Спасибо, я учту это в будущем!